# Detach a terminal from a process in D (uninterruptible sleep) state

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, zsh

I have a shell command in stuck in D state (imagine doing `ls` on a NFS share when the network is down).

How do I detach from such a command? I can't kill the process in any way (well, it's called "uninterruptible" for a reason), and ctrl-z does nothing, so I have no place to type `detach`.

Please don't propose workarounds (like "just open new terminal", "use screen/tmux", etc.), I know them, I'm just curious for a better solution =)

PS:
This may be a duplicate, but all I was able to find is threads like "Q:ctrl-c does not work A: use kill-9"